# $\mathbb{E}[M_{a}]\geq \mathbb{E}[M_{b}]$ with $a,b$ limited stopping times and $M$ sub-martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, limsup-and-liminf, stopping-times

I don't understand why $$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[e^{-r(T-t)}X_T\mid \Im_t]\geq \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[e^{-r(\tau-t)}X_{\tau}\mid \Im_t] \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[e^{-r(T-t)}X_T\mid \Im_t]\geq \sup_{\tau}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[e^{-r(\tau-t)}X_{\tau}\mid \Im_t]$$

Let $\begin{Bmatrix}
X_t
\end{Bmatrix}_{t\in [0,+\infty)}$ be a sub-martingale $\Im_t$-adapted, with $\tau:=(t+s) \leq T \space \mathbb{P}$-$ \operatorname{a.s.}$ for $T$ generical stopping time.

Now, if $$\sup_{\tau}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[e^{-r(T-t)}X_T\mid \Im_t]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[e^{-r(T-t)}X_T\mid \Im_t]$$ because the variable $\tau$ is not the variable of interest...

...why if $\tau \leq T$ also $\sup_{\tau} \leq T$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by definition of supremum.

Comment: @UBM Could you be more specific, in the context?

Comment: Do you understand the definition of supremum in real analysis?

Comment: @UBM Yes. Example: for $X$ totally ordered set and $A\subseteq X$, writing $\operatorname{Sup}A\leq x \leq \operatorname{Inf}A$ means that $x$ is not less than the upper bound of $A$ and not more that the lower bound of $A$. But here I am in confusion because of the stopping times.

Comment: if we have $y \in \mathbb R$ and $A \subset \mathbb R$ such that $x \leq y$ for all  $x \in A,$ then $\sup A \leq y,$ right?$

Comment: @UBM Yes. And so?